# Async P/Invoke calls

Tags: c#

I'm working on a wrapping library for a robot controller, that mostly relies on P/Invoke calls.

However, a lot of the functionality for the robot, such as homing, or movement, takes quite a while, and do thread locks while running.

So I'm wondering how I can wrap the functionality in a async manner, so the calls don't block my UI thread. My idea so far is to use Tasks, but I'm not really sure it's the right approach.

```
public Task<bool> HomeAsync(Axis axis, CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Home(axis), token);
}
```

Most of the MSDN articles on the Async model in .NET as of right now, mostly is relaying on libraries already having Async functionality (such as File.BeginRead and so on). But I can't seem to find much information on how to actually write the async functionality in the first place.

Comment: What kind of interface are you using? Or is this a library that has to be build independently of a specific interface?

Comment: Assuming you mean UI interface, the application build on top of it is WPF. But I'd prefer to handle it on library level, so the UI team don't have to worry to much about threading.

Comment: Robot interface don't normally work this way.  You'd completely lose control over the device, you couldn't even abort the homing move.  A home command normally just starts the homing move, you'd then poll or get a signal when it is completed.  Check what's available in the interface before you commit to doing it this way.

Comment: I don't get any signal when it's done. And it's a legacy piece of equipment on the university , back from the early 90s. I'm pretty confident in what's necessary.

Comment: I have a similar problem. What was your final. Implementation.

Comment: These days the problem is solved with async programming. you declare your method as `public async Task<bool>...` and in the body you write `return await Task.Run(() => Home(axis), token).ConfigureAwait(false)`. The `ConfigureAwait(false)` is the important part as it makes your code to not block the UI (it actually says that the continuation doesn't need to be run on the synchronization context of the method that called HomeAsync.

Comment: As a second thought, it would be better to have a natively async method (`HomeAsync`) and wrap it within a synchronous call (`Home`) rather than the other way around. The way you built it, consumes one thread. You actually have one thread waiting idle, that can't be used by the thread pool, and it just isn't your UI thread. But still it is waiting. True asynchronous operations don't consume threads. In the lower level they rely on the hardware and IO interrupts to resume execution, thus leaving all threads available for use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you ever tried [async delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx)? I believe there is nothing simpler than it.

If your thread-blocking method is `void Home(Axis)` you have first to define a delegate type, ie. `delegate void HomeDelegate(Axis ax)`, then use the `BeginInvoke` method of a new instance of HomeDelegate pointing to the address of Home method.

```
[DllImport[...]] //PInvoke
void Home(Axis x);

delegate void HomeDelegate(Axis x);

void main()
{
    HomeDelegate d = new HomeDelegate(Home);
    IAsyncResult ia = d.BeginInvoke(axis, null, null);
    [...]
    d.EndInvoke(ia);
}
```

Please bear in mind that using the EndInvoke somewhere (blocking the thread until the method is finally over, maybe in conjunction with polling of IAsyncResult.Completed property) is very useful to check if your async task has really been completed. You might not want your robot to open its arm and leave a glass until the glass is over the table, you know ;-)

Comment: And you don't even need to define delegate types anymore. Just use `Action<Axis>`.

Comment: I believe the Task Parallel Library wraps all that into the Task class, no ?

Answer (score 6):

After some great discussion, I think something like this will be the golden middleway.

```
public void HomeAsync(Axis axis, Action<bool> callback)
{
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => Home(axis))
        .ContinueWith(task => callback(task.Result));
}
```

This is using the best of both worlds, I think.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is that this is not something you should do in the library. The primary reason is that the way you implement such a system may depend on the type of interface you are building upon the library.

That said, you have basically two choices. First is the `IAsyncResult`. A good description of this can be found at http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/02/24/asyncdelegates.html.

The second option is to create commands with callback events. The user creates a command class and sets a callback on that. Then, you schedule the command to a `ThreadPool` and after the command has been executed, you raise that event.

Older interfaces of the .NET framework primarily implemented the `IAsyncResult` approach, where newer interfaces tend to implement the event callback approach.

Comment: And queuing a item on a ThreadPool doesn't block the UI Thread? Even if I have events telling when a operation is done, it's rather pointless if I need to wrap all calls into threads anyway to avoid UI blocking.

Comment: Queueing it to the `ThreadPool` does not block, no. The whole reason for using a callback interface is that you can leave synchronization to the UI interface implementation. You just provide a way to signal the UI that you're done, and the UI takes it from there. Another advantage is that the callbacks are optional, so when the UI does not need notification, it just doesn't register a callback and just fires and forgets.

Comment: Yeah, but the callback model were also my first suggestion. I take it that people are unfamiliar with TPL?

Comment: My question is why you would use TPL? TPL has a different purpose, namely introducing parallel code constructs (the `ForEach` is a good example). What you're doing is asynchronous operations, and the `IAsyncResult` or `ThreadPool` approach fits that better.

Comment: Except the IAsyncResult model requires a crazy amount of unncessary boilerplate code. TPL isn't just for parallel code, but also for async operations. Hejlsberg even just confirmed it yesterday at his PDC talk.

Comment: Yes, I know the `IAsyncResult` requires a lot of boilerplate. That's why I would use the callback mechanism :). The only reason I mentioned it, is because it's available.

Comment: Sure, but adding in a callback doesn't automatically make the code run async, and doesn't stop the UI thread blocking.

Comment: The idea is that the `ThreadPool` executes the command (incl. the pinvoke) and inside the thread of the `ThreadPool`, raises the callback event.